# Problem adding javascript into PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: javascript, itext

I am trying to embed JavaScript into pdf that is created using iTextSharp and it is working absolutely fine if it is a file as shown in the code.

But when I try to embed the javascript part into a memory stream it is not working. Are there any limitations of iTextSharp??

```
Dim js As New StringBuilder
                Dim pdf As String = "c:\Print2Printer.pdf"
                Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(pdf, FileMode.Create))
                doc.Open()

                js.Append("var pp = this.getPrintParams();")
                js.Append("var iCopies = 2;")
                js.Append("pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;")
                js.Append("for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) { pp.firstPage = i; pp.lastPage = i;")
                js.Append("this.print(pp);")
                js.Append("}")
                Dim jaction As PdfAction = PdfAction.JavaScript(js.ToString(), writer)
                writer.AddJavaScript(jaction)

                doc.Add(New Paragraph(pdfString))
                doc.Close()
```

Comment: If all you're doing is replacing the FileStream with a MemoryStream, then it should be functionally identical.  You still have to put that memory stream somewhere you can look at it (like a file) in order to see the JS and its effects.  How are you opening the memoryStream?

Comment: @rowmark, what is the argument that you have passed for `New Paragraph(pdfString)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your PDF is not rendered yet... I am not sure if PDF has a onreadystate event or not but see... http://mattheyan.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-javascript-to-pdf-document-with.html

In short you need a setTimeout

Here is an example using Docotic.Pdf http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380293/Javascript-in-PDF